# MVC 4 Forms authentication strange behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, forms-authentication

I am using Asp.Net with MVC 4 to build a web application. For authentication, I am using forms authentication. The login page is set correctly and login behaves properly. However, instead of using the default partial login view I am using my own and I use AJAX to log in.

The login controller works fine and here is the code for login.

Here is my code in login action. Here resp is my custom response object

```
resp.Status = true;
// sometimes used to persist user roles
string userData = "some user data";
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
  1,                                     // ticket version
  login.username,                        // authenticated username
  DateTime.Now,                          // issueDate
  DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),           // expiryDate
  false,                          // true to persist across browser sessions
  userData,                              // can be used to store additional user data
  FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);  // the path for the cookie
// Encrypt the ticket using the machine key
string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
// Add the cookie to the request to save it
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
cookie.HttpOnly = true;
//Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
Response.SetCookie(cookie);

return Json(resp);
```

Here is the code of cshtml page to handle this script response

```
function (respData) {
                    if (respData.Status) {
                        window.location.href = "/";
                    }
                    if (!respData.Status) {
                        if (respData.Errors[0].ErrorCode == 1) {
                            $('#invalid').show();
                            $('#username').val('');
                            $('#password').val('');
                        }
                        else if (respData.Errors[0].ErrorCode == -1) {
                            var msg = respData.Errors[0].ErrorDescription;
                            $('#error_email').text(msg);
                        }
                        else {
                            var msg = respData.Errors[0].ErrorDescription;
                            $('#error_pwd').text(msg);
                        }
                    }
                    $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                },
```

Everything works fine and the user is successfully redirected to home page on successful login. Also gets a proper message on failure.

The problem is, when I browse any other page after this successful redirection, the subsequent requests are not authenticated.

I did a little bit research and found that the browser is not sending the forms authentication cookie  in the subsequent requests and hence those requests are not authenticated.

Any idea on this behavior ? , Am I missing something ?

Comment: What FormsAuthentication settings do you have in your web.config? I'm wondering what the cookie PATH is set to.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting the expiry time on your cookie with:

```
Cookie.Expires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30));
```

Comment: Tried it out. Nothing changed. More strange is, it actually sends cookie in next request but not subsequent requests.